# Simple Clean Math Operations

Tags: python, args

I'm trying to make some basic methods for handling python math operations, I made a method for getting the sum of all numbers in the args like these:

```py
def get_sum_of_numbers(*args):
    temp_value = 0
    for num in args:
        temp_value += num
    return temp_value
```

The problem is that when I try to create a simple average method:

```py
def get_average_of_numbers(*args):
    return get_sum_of_numbers(args) / len(args)
```

I can't reuse this method because I can't just pass to the sum method the args of the average method as an argument, I want to make both the average method and the sum method take as many numbers as the programmer wishes to input. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are returning `temp_value` too soon; dedent it.

Comment: `sum` is already a built-in function in Python; no need to redefine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `*` before [args]

```py
def get_average_of_numbers(*args):
    return get_sum_of_numbers(*args) / len(args)
```

and, yes, Tobi208 is right, You have incorrect indentation, see his answer, I don't want to steal his :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*` operator again

```
def get_average_of_numbers(*args):
    return get_sum_of_numbers(*args) / len(args)
```

Are you sure your `get_sum_of_numbers` function is doing what it's supposed to do though? Looks like it simply returns the value of the first arg. Why not do

```
def get_sum_of_numbers(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

or if you don't want to use `sum`

```
def get_sum_of_numbers(*args):
    temp_value = 0
    for num in args:
        temp_value += num
    return temp_value  # correct indentation
```